# Oracle listener TNS-01153 : Failed to Process the String

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I changed IP Server address which installed Oracle 11g on windows server. But my listener service has not worked so I can't access from the remote. Below are my listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )   )

LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ORA_DB)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )   )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\Administrator
```

I didn't figure out what i was wrong. Should I change HOST = ORA_DB to server's IP address

Comment: You might want to post this on https://dba.stackexchange.com if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: @James Z  thanks for your advice. I already posted my questions to this site.